# Passing 'data source' between activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to have a generic 'Chooser' activity - one which can be provided with abstract data source, extract data from said source, present the data in a `ListView` and return the selected item back to calling activity. Something very akin to `RingtonePickerActivity`.

What I can't figure out is how to pass generic data source from one activity to another. All that I have seen so far in term of sharing data between activities is by passing data through `Intent`'s extras. But that doesn't seem to work for me here, since I do not want to provide the actual data - I want to pass a reference to abstract data source, which can be queried (not unlike the `Cursor`).

The point I'd like to emphasize is that I'd like the chooser to be agnostic of the actual source of data - abstract data source would provide methods like `getNextItem`, `getItemName`, `getItemValue`. The best models of this I can think of are Cursors or Iterators - a purely abstract mechanisms of iterating over set of data.

Since all activities of the application are hosted in the same process, this should  be possible? One thing I **do not want** to do is to have a global data source variable inside my application, for the multitude of reasons (one of them being the fact that I will be running multiple chooser activities with multiple data sources) - I want to provide the data to the activity being started at start time.

Is it possible? Am I terribly misguided? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that doesn't seem to work for me here, since I do not want to provide the actual data - I want to pass a reference to abstract data source, which can be queried (not unlike the Cursor).

Pass an extra or `Uri` that identifies the abstract data source. Use that information to then query that data source.

For example, suppose that the "abstract data source" is a Web service. Your activity will need to know enough about the Web service to know what sort of data comes back, simply because the activity has to have rendering rules for that data (i.e., what to show for rows in the list). But, perhaps the actual URL for the Web service varies. Pass the URL as an extra, or as the "data" of the `Intent` (via `setData(Uri.parse(theUrlThatYouWant))`. Your activity can then use something like Retrofit to retrieve the data in a background thread and use the results in the list.

Since we have no idea what your "abstract data source" is, we cannot readily help you further. In general, what you are passing to the activity is some identifier that allows the activity to look up the data source. What you use for you identifiers, and for that lookup mechanism, is up to you and may tie into what the "abstract data source" is.

You are welcome to have generic UI populated by arbitrary data sources, but those arbitrary data sources cannot be passed around via an `Intent`, since `Intent` objects are designed to be passed across process boundaries. Your primary choices are:

1. Use inheritance and polymorphism. Have an abstract chooser activity that does most of the work, with subclasses that can obtain the data given simple identifiers.
2. Use some in-activity UI, such as a fragment, since you are no longer limited by `Intent` structures and can pass around whatever is needed.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough. The point is, I want 'Chooser' activity to get the data without knowing where it comes from. Cursor is probably a good example - I want the activity to be able to extract data from the source without knowing anything about it. Another model might be an abstract iterator - something you can ask for the next item.

Comment: @SergeyA: "I want the activity to be able to extract data from the source without knowing anything about it" -- um, well, `Cursor` does not work that way. `Cursor` *is* the data, and you have stated that you do not want to pass the actual data. To get a `Cursor`, you need to know how to retrieve it. That could be a database name and a query, or that could be a `ContentProvider` `Uri` and a query. "Another model might be an abstract iterator - something you can ask for the next item" -- um, that is not how iterators work either, as you are then passing the data.

Comment: I tried to edit the question for clarity. Let me know if it makes more sense or no sense :)

Comment: @SergeyA: Please understand that all activity invocations involve IPC, even if both the originating activity and the activity being started are in the same app and the same process. This is why you cannot pass arbitrary objects in `Intent` extras, as arbitrary objects cannot be passed across process boundaries.

Comment: May be I am not using proper terms for Java  - I am from C++, we have slightly different meaning for iterators. I see iterator as a querying mechanism - it doesn't really store the data, but it knows how to extract the data from underlying source. Let's imagine I have a huge array of, say, 100000 items (not practical for chooser, but good for illustration). I want to start a Chooser activity and provide it with  iterator to this array - not array itself, since I do not want to copy 100000 elements. Makes sense?

Comment: Ok, we are getting somewhere. But my activities are in the same process! There is no crossing process boundaries here! So even in this case I can't achieve my goal (hope it is clearer now?)

Comment: @SergeyA: "here is no crossing process boundaries here!" -- yes, there is. `startActivity()` performs IPC to a core OS process, which determines where the activity that needs to be started resides. It then does IPC back to your originating process.

Comment: Alright, understood. And I guess, there is no way to start activity directly? Is there any other way to present the user with something which allows user to choose one option out of several? (Again, the example I have is ringtone chooser)

Comment: @SergeyA: You are certainly welcome to do what you want to do here, but it would have to be all in one activity, such as by having a chooser fragment. Otherwise, as I wrote, the chooser activity would have to pull the data in via some sort of simple identifiers. Going back to your `Cursor` analogy, you can pass in the name of the database and the SQL query via extras, then have the chooser activity execute the query to get the `Cursor`.

Comment: Chooser fragment is actually a neat idea! I will be willing to accept the answer if you incorporate this suggestion into it. As for the Cursor, yes, I understand that I can pass DB name and the query, the problem is, data would come from different sources - DB would be one, but there would also be arrays of pre-populated data.

Answer (score 1):

I only know these ways to pass data around activities.

1. Pass data through intent.
2. If your data are created inside a Service you can create a ServiceConnection in both activities and have access to your data from both having a getData() method inside the service.
3. Make data global or temporarily global (nullify the reference once you 're done with it so that memory is released)
4. Pass some form of instruction through the intent so that the new Activity can recreate the same data. If for example your data came from querying a database then you can pass the query as a string to activity B. Then activity B can perform that query and get the same data.

Also maybe you'd like to go with this in another direction. For example something I 've used many times is a chooser Dialog instead of a chooser Activity. This way you show your chooser without leaving your Activity and you just pass the data to your Dialog constructor. And you can configure the Dialog to be full screen so it can look the same way an Activity does to the user. A fragment could also serve the same purpose.

Comment: Please see my comments to the other answer. I was trying to make my intention clearer.